# JSF outputText overflows

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to show status comments inside a panel with below code:

```
<p:panel>
    <ui:repeat var="Comment" value="#{Status.commentList}">
        <h:outputText value="#{Comment.Text}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:panel>
```

It seems when the comments are so long, text is overflowing from the panel. I've investigated it and found out `h:outputText` is generating a span and tried to solve this via CSS:

```
<h:outputText value="#{Comment.Text}"
    style="width: 100px!important; overflow-x: scroll!important;"/>
```

Giving a fixed width and `overflow-x:scroll` should do the trick but it renders span much wider, even I've set it as 100px, it renders it as 400 pixels taking no notice of `!important`.

Comment: You try to get exactly outputtext area, may be caught by parent of outputtext.

Comment: It seems I forgot one more thing: `display:block` solved the Issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:outputText value="#{Comment.Text}"
    style="width: 100px; overflow-x: scroll; display:block;"/>
```

Is the correct way. W3 says about `display:block`;

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other,
>   vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical
>   distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin'
>   properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block boxes in a block
>   formatting context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a
>   box's content area may shrink due to the floats).

This proofs why my text was overflowing it needs to be handled as a context value.

Comment: Get rid of `!important`. They make no utter sense inside `style` attributes. They are only useful in CSS style definitions in an external CSS file. Their whole point is to prevent that a CSS property definied in the `style` attribute overrides the style definition in the external CSS file.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for additional information. Actually I've asked a new question which is deeper and related with this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15901896/1659451). Should this question needs to be closed?